# (DOORS/DXL) Is it possible to programmatically edit/modify Object Text/Object Heading?

Tags: scripting, ibm-doors

Is it possible to programmatically edit/modify Object Text/Object Heading?

If so, how do you do it? I can edit my other attributes just fine programmatically. I can edit the Object Text fine in DOORs, however not through DXL,

It says
"No access to modify attribute "Object Text""

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never declared something like this
const Module currentModule = current

Instead, I just kept using the keyword "current" to refer to my current module.

After using the currentModule variable instead of "current" it fixed my problem.

Answer (score 3):

That sounds like you have a permissions issue perhaps, but if that is not the case your code should look like this:

```
Object o = current
o."Object Text" = "This is my test text"
```

That is the same for any attribute. If that doesn't work for you please post as much of your code as you can so we can see what might be going wrong.